# Change Database on the fly in Entity Framework same scheme

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a context which I derive my entity I have 5 databases these database are off the same scheme that I need to switch from at run time. The user would be selecting at the launch of the application which database they would be connecting to.

The database that is of the same scheme is SMBASchedulerEntities its just the catalogue name that is different

```
public class SourceContext : ContextBase
{
    public SMBASchedulerEntities _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities();
    public SystemDa _systemDB = new SystemDa();

    public void AddToPatient(Patient newPatient)
    {
        _sourceEntities.Patients.Add(newPatient);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void AddToAppointmentTypes(AppointmentType AppointmentTypes)
    {
        _sourceEntities.AppointmentTypes.Add(AppointmentTypes);
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

As you can see there I reference the entities within my context so I would like to have a property that I can call such as `changeDatabase` and that it would take affect without restarting the application is that at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the **connection string** you want to connect to, when instantiating your `DbContext`. First, you declare your `DbContext` like so:

```
public class SMBASchedulerEntities : DbContext
{
    public SMBASchedulerEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

You keep all your connection strings in your `Web.config` or `App.config` (depending on the type of project):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection1" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MyAppUser;password=SecretPass;database=MyDatabase1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection2" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MyAppUser;password=SecretPass;database=MyDatabase2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection3" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MyAppUser;password=SecretPass;database=MyDatabase3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection4" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MyAppUser;password=SecretPass;database=MyDatabase4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection5" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MyAppUser;password=SecretPass;database=MyDatabase5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you use it like this:

```
using (var db = new SMBASchedulerEntities("DefaultConnection1"))
{
    // use MyDatabase1 through connection string "DefaultConnection1"
}

using (var db = new SMBASchedulerEntities("DefaultConnection2"))
{
    // use MyDatabase2 through connection string "DefaultConnection2"
}
```

---

### Dispose your `DbContext`

It's recommended to dispose the `DbContext` after using it. If you still want to use your idea with `SourceContext`, you could implement something like this:

```
public class SourceContext : ContextBase, IDisposable
{
    public SMBASchedulerEntities _sourceEntities;
    public SystemDa _systemDB = new SystemDa();

    public SourceContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities(connectionString);
    }

    public void AddToPatient(Patient newPatient)
    {
        _sourceEntities.Patients.Add(newPatient);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void ChangeDatabaseTo(string connectionString)
    {
        if (_sourceEntities != null)
            _sourceEntities.Dispose();
        _sourceEntities = new SMBASchedulerEntities(connectionString);
    }

    public void AddToAppointmentTypes(AppointmentType AppointmentTypes)
    {
        _sourceEntities.AppointmentTypes.Add(AppointmentTypes);
        SaveChanges();


    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_sourceEntities != null)
            {
                _sourceEntities.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

...then finally use it like this:

```
using(var context = new SourceContext("DefaultConnection1"))
{
    context.AddPatient(patient); // add to Database1

    context.ChangeDatabaseTo("DefaultConnection2");

    context.AddPatient(patient); // add to Database2

    context.ChangeDatabaseTo("DefaultConnection4");

    context.AddPatient(patient); // add to Database4
}
```

---

By making your `SourceContext` an `IDisposable`, you have the opportunity to properly dispose the `DbContext` instance. Take note I took care of disposing the existing `DbContext` before changing it.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer I am trying to get away from eidting the application everytime a new database is created I want to just have a table with the information and references it that way is their anyway of doing that.

Comment: @davidbuc these new databases have the same schema as the existing ones, is that right? You want to connect to a database without having to edit the connection strings?

Comment: Yes that is correct there be a database table called providers which will have the database name and any other information I need within that table that be in a system database sep to the sep schemas dbs

Comment: You get the connection string from wherever, and simply pass the full connection string to that same DbContext constructor.

Comment: Dull, yes.  But you seemed unaware that you can simply pass the full connection string to that same constructor.

Answer (score -1):

So, turns out the easiest way to do this is to put all of the DB names and connection strings in the appsettings.json file.

You can make it very complex, of course, but what I did was make a select drop down, let the user select the DB they want to use, then fire the onclick method to pull the connection string out of the app settings.json file, create an instance of the DBCONTEXT with that name’s connection string and use that DB context throughout whatever you need from there.

```
Public static class AppSettings
{
    public static string GetConnectionString(string sDBinstanceName)
    {
    IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetpathName(<wherever your appsettings.json file is>,”appsettings.json”).ReadJsonFile();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
    var tmpSettings = Configuration.GeyAppSettings();
    string dbConstr = tmpSettings[“ConnectionStrings”][sDBinstanceName];
    return dbConstr;
    }
}
```

This is not MY snippet, but a derivative of what I found online.  As it is from memory, it is not 100% correct, but I will fix it on Monday.  I will update with author when I find it again(Monday).

Once you get the connection string you treat the DBCONTEXT like any other object, create it, use the tables (MEF) and whatever else you need, then destroy it correctly or let the garbage collection clean it up.

I got this working yesterday and please note: There are ZERO DBCONTEXTs registered in the Program.cs file as they are not needed.

This system is simple, lets you allow the user control to which Database they need based on a simple selection mechanism and answers the question.

At our shop we have MULTIPLE databases with exact same schema because we segregate data based on the timeframe for that data, but I can envision situations where you could use different schemas depending on the selection, we just do not do that.

For instance we have a Production and Development DB that are EXACTLY the same schema (different data) so the one DBCONTEXT is used for both in MEF.

With the method above we can let the user see the data in either at their command, it’s just getting there is a whole lot easier.

Comment: Please do not create an answer with no examples you should wait until you have enough reputation https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362336/require-reputation-for-answer-not-for-comment

Comment: Sorry about that.